# Install go (golang) on Raspbian

Tags: linux, go, installation, raspbian

I checked diverse forums but I still did not make it working.
I like to install go (golang) on my Raspberry PI - Raspbian:

With

```
sudo apt-get install golang
```

I installed go and with

```
export GOPATH=$home/pi/gocode
```

i set the GOPATH so i tryed to install from a homepage a new program with (`sudo go get -u github.com/....`) but, I only get "`cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath`".

I really get crazy for my studip simple mistake that i do not see.

I would be pleased if i get a very detailed "how to do" discription since I am new to Linux and Raspbian, so everything which is made for real dummys should be good enough for me. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: _Never_ build using `sudo`. just use `go get`, `go build`, `go install`, etc.

Comment: As @JimB said don't use sudo to run the go command. You just need it to install it and your already did it with `sudo apt-get`.

Just to let you know, you have set the GOPATH to your user when doing that export. But when you run somethin with `sudo` you are running a command as the `root` user which has not set the GOPATH. `sudo` -> "Do as super user"

Comment: Also, of you're getting a `$GOPATH not set` error, you're using an old version of Go. You may want to use the binary install directly from golang.org. if it's available for your os/arch.

Comment: How to make go working:

download the latest version of go in a new folder (like download)

go1.9.linux-armv6l.tar.gz    in a new directory like download



install with 

sudo apt-get install golang    

an older version of go (golang)  in my case it was 1.7.4


then use

sudo tar -C /home/pi -xzf go1.9.linux-armv6l.tar.gz

Comment: to install go version 1.9

in a new directory  in my case 

home/pi/go


with 

sudo apt remove golang

and

sudo apt-get autoremove

remove the older version of go

to check unse 

go version

which give you the actual version of go

it should be go1.9 linux/arm


please check with 

go env

or

go env GOPATH

the GOPATH direction

Comment: with 

ls -a   (used in /home/pi/ )

give you a list of all files and also shows you ~/.profile

with 

sudo nano ~/.profile

you can open that file an add the recomanded code for the go directory

 
 export GOROOT=/home/pi/go
 export GOPATH=/home/pi/go/bin



close with STRG + O  and ENTER  and STRG + X

check with 

go env GOPATH

then use

source ~/.profile


Now go should be running on the latest version and should have the correct GOPATH directory


For me helpful was
https://tecadmin.net/install-go-on-debian/#

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This are detailed instructions about how to install Go on Raspbian Stretch from the repositories.

As of today, 2018-01-30, this will install Go 1.7. The most actual version for manual installation from the downloads is Go 1.9.3.

I. Login to your user on the Raspberry Pi (I'm using the default user pi).

II. Install Go (golang)

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ sudo apt update 
pi@pi3-2:~ $ sudo apt install golang
```

III. Create a working directory for all your go projects in your $HOME directory. It's best to name it go, as this defaults to the GOPATH in future Go versions (starting with Go 1.8).

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ mkdir go
```

IV. Append the $GOPATH environment variable and modified PATH settings to your .profile

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go' >> ~/.profile
pi@pi3-2:~ $ echo 'PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

V. Logout and Relog with the new settings then check your settings

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ go env

GOARCH="arm"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/pi/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.7"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.7/pkg/tool/linux_arm"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build187598155=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Especially make sure GOPATH points to your previously created Go working directory. Don't care about setting GOBIN as mentioned in some documentation. It's usually not necessary and Go will automatically use $GOPATH/bin/ for your Go installs.

However, you might also want to check the path settings (/home/pi/go/bin should be included) to make sure you can run the code you installed with go install.

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ echo $PATH
/home/pi/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

VI. A few words about the Go working directory structure

Over time, the Go working directory will contain three sub-directories: bin, src and pkg. Except src they will be automatically created, when needed the first time. The structure for user pi will look like this:

```
/home
  /pi
    /go
      /src
      /pkg
      /bin
```

**bin** will contain all Go executable's you have installed using go install command.

**pkg** will contain all compiled packages that can be imported into your projects.

**src** will contain all your source files, either your own or sources downloaded from external repositories.

For eksample the command `go get github.com/petergloor/hello-go` will automatically fetch and place the source files from the corresponding external Github repository into the local directory *$HOME/go/src/github.com/petergloor/hello-go*.

As it's rather common to fetch external repositories either for reference or contribution it becomes important to keep your directory structure always well organized and clean.

Apart from that you are free to organize your projects as long they are hierarchically structured below the $HOME/go/src/ directory and follow the rules mentioned in the documentation.

However, to clearly organize my projects I personally always place my projects into $HOME/go/src/github.com/my-github-account even if I don't have an external repository for it.

If you don't have a github account you can likewise use any other external repository account.

As I mentioned, even it's not needed at all I prefere to use my Github account to clearly identify my projects. And even it's not needed I will use the username pi to distinct the user from other project maintainers in the following example.

VII. So let's add a "hello world" project to test our installation.

a) First let's create the project folder and cd into its directory.

```
pi@pi3-2:~ $ mkdir -p $HOME/go/src/pi/helloworld
pi@pi3-2:~ $ cd $HOME/go/src/pi/helloworld
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $
```

b) With an editor of your choice create a file main.go with the following content

```
// helloworld project main.go.
package main

import ("fmt")

// main is the entrypoint of the application.
func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world! Greetings from Raspberry Pi")
}
```

Spacing doesn't matter at this point. Go provides a nice tool to do this for you.

c) Now try to run the program.

```
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ go run main.go
Hello world! Greetings from Raspberry Pi
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $
```

In case you get an error, fix it! Carefully, check the spelling and cases  (Go is case-sensitive).

d) Next lets format the code:

```
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ go fmt
```

Without a file name this will properly (re-)format all source files within this directory and below.

e) Next let's build helloworld as an executable procram, within this directory.

```
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ go build
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ ls
helloworld  main.go
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $
```

f) Now you can run it.

```
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ ./helloworld
Hello world! Greetings from Raspberry Pi
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $
```

g) Finally let's install the program into the $HOME/go/bin/ directory.

```
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ go install
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ ls $HOME/go/bin
hello-go  helloworld
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $
```

h) If everything is done right it can be run by our pi user from anywhere by just entering the name of the command.

```
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ helloworld
Hello world! Greetings from Raspberry Pi
pi@pi3-2:~/go/src/pi/helloworld $ cd ~
pi@pi3-2:~ $ helloworld
Hello world! Greetings from Raspberry Pi
pi@pi3-2:~ $
```

Congratulations!

Comment: Thank you @Peter. I've followed your well-written steps and everything works!
this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: as awesome as the instructions are, and their great for testing out a new install of the go lang tooling, putting that helloworld directory within the `$HOME/go/src` directory will prevent packages from updating using `go get -u [github.com/user/go-pkg]` the `go get` cmd will complain about having a directory within the `src` dir that hasn't been initialized with a VCS. see [this](https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/116)

Answer (score 3):

as of Nov 2019. (Please note if you need version 1.13+ please wget `go1.13.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz` manually)
OR `sudo apt-get install golang-go` - [source](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu)

You just have to type following commands on your RPi

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang --fix-missing
```

and when you type now `go version` following should be your output

```
pi@rpi1:~ $ go version
go version go1.11.6 linux/arm
```

Additionally, I also had the following installed before running everything
`sudo apt-get install make gcc g++`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

How to install golang:

Download the latest tarball, *go1.9.linux-armv6l.tar.gz*, to a directory such as */home/pi/downloads*.

Then use:

`sudo tar -C /home/pi -xzf go1.9.linux-armv6l.tar.gz`

to extract the go installation to the directory

*/home/pi*

creating */home/pi/go*

to check use

`go version`

Which will give you the actual version of go.

It should be go1.9 linux/arm.

Please check with:

`go env`

or

`go env GOPATH`

the **GOPATH** direction

with

`ls -a #  (used in /home/pi/ )`

give you a list of all files and also shows you *~/.profile*

with

`sudo nano ~/.profile`

you can open that file an add the reccommended code for the go directory

```
 export GOROOT=/home/pi/go
 export GOPATH=/home/pi/go/bin
```

close with STRG + O  and ENTER  and STRG + X

check with

`go env GOPATH`

then use

`source ~/.profile`

then you can check again with

`go env`

Now go should be running on the latest version and should have the correct **GOPATH** directory

For me helpful was this link: https://tecadmin.net/install-go-on-debian/#

I really hope some others also give detailed descriptions of how to install a program in a brief and detailed way. Instead of 3 lines of single code.

Comment: ok, one more comment on that    


export GOPATH =/home/pi/go

export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/go/bin

in the ~/.profile   document

otherwise i got an error wenn trying to run go
but now it works perfectly, no errors or anything even with the older version 1.7.4 of golang.

so i really hope this helps others  or me later on, when setting up again